# Supervisord: How to use the hostname in a startup command

Tags: supervisord

is it possible to somehow use the local hostname in a supervisord startup script?
I need it to pass the jmx host to a java-Program.
Example:

```
command=HOSTNAME=foo.bar /usr/local/rvm/bin/jruby-1.7.1 script/trinidad.rb --threadsafe -f config/trinidad_user_production.rb
```

I see no easy option so far.

Best,

Tobias

Comment: That looks like a environment variable setting to me, correct?

Comment: Yes, there is no 'easy' way as far as I can tell. The only way as of now that I know is same as what Martijn Pieters has suggested. I too would love to not to have to create an environment variable for this.

Answer (score 11):

For using hostname in the config file:

> %(host_node_name)s

Answer (score 0):

`environment=HOSTNAME=foo.bar` should work without any issues.

See: http://supervisord.org/subprocess.html#subprocess-environment